# wxWidgets taskBarIcon unavailable on Ubuntu 22.04 unless run from vscode integrated terminal

Tags: terminal, wxwidgets, taskbar, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to port a wxWidgets application to linux and I've been struggling with it.

I'm running an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine on Win11. When I run the built application from the integrated terminal in VSCODE the taskbaricon appears, but when I run it from the system terminal it doesn't. Also there are differences in size, it is smaller when starting from the system one.

I though there is something wrong with my code, so I used the [their sample](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_helloworld.html) and modified the constructor of `MyFrame` to this:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    if(!wxTaskBarIcon::IsAvailable())
    {
        wxMessageBox(wxT("Hello World!"));
    }

    wxTaskBarIcon *tb = new wxTaskBarIcon();
    tb->SetIcon(icon, "TEST");
}
```

Nothing changes, same behaviour. I also built the [taskbar sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/master/samples/taskbar), again same thing.

I am going insane and have no idea of what's going on. Is this happening because I'm on a virtual machine? Why is there a difference between launching from the integrated terminal in vscode and the linux one? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you running in Wayland or X? What GNOME version do you have? What GTK+ version exactly?

Comment: Also - did you see this: https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/1680?

Comment: And finally - using the `task bar icon` is discouraged by the GTK devs as in the default GNOME no task bar is present. And so you will need to find another way to use that on *nix...

Comment: Wayland, gtk version is 3.24.33. I didn't see that post, I'll take a look. Even though a taskbaricon is discouraged I still find it weird that it works when launched from the integrated terminal in vscode and not otherwise. If it works from there why wouldn't it work otherwise?

Comment: yes it is weird. I presume you are using GNOME? While this post I referenced is about KDE it still applies.

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed the problem, at least for Ubuntu, switching to Xorg solves the issue, the taskbar icon is visible and the window is the right size